# Submodule Isomorphic to quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some questions related to a proof I'm working on. I ultimately want to prove that for the ideal $I = (2,x)$ of the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ that $I \otimes_R I$ generated by $2 \otimes x - x \otimes 2$ is isomorphic to $R/I$.

Now I'm having some uncertainty. Is not the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,2)$ simply comprised of $0$ and $1$?

Also, the difference of two simple tensors as module generator is a bit mysterious.

I would appreciate any nudging context.

Comment: $[x]/(x,2)\simeq\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]/(x)\simeq \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:R\to I\otimes_RI$ be the only $R$-module homomorphism such that $\varphi(1)=x\otimes 2-2\otimes x$.
Then $I\subseteq\ker\varphi$, so that we get an $R$-module homomorphism $\bar\varphi:R/I\to I\otimes_RI$.
We have an exact sequence of $R$-modules:
$$\{0\}\to R\xrightarrow\kappa R^2\xrightarrow\xi I\to\{0\}$$
where
\begin{align}
&\kappa(r)=(-2r,xr)&
&\xi(u,v)=xu+2v
\end{align}
for every $r\in R$ and $u,v\in R$.
There exists one and only one $R$-module homomorphism  $\varrho:R^2\otimes_RR^2\to R/I$ such that $\varrho((a,b)\otimes(c,d))=ad+I$.
Then $\xi\otimes_R\xi:R^2\otimes_RR^2\to I\otimes_RI$ is surjective and $\ker(\xi\otimes_R\xi)\subseteq\ker\varrho$.
Thus there exists an $R$-module homomorphism $\psi:I\otimes_RI\to R/I$ making the following diagram commutative:

[image]

where $\sigma(1)=(1,0)\otimes(0,1)-(0,1)\otimes(1,0)$.
Since $\pi$ is surjective, this proves $\ker\varphi=I$, hence $\bar\varphi:R/I\to I\otimes_R I$ induces an $R$-module isomorphism onto its image.